Vote reminder banner violates accessibility standards
The close text on Stack Overflow's vote reminder banner fails every color contrast accessibility standard and is illegible. See failures: Contrast Checker


"How do I let Stack Overflow know ..." First step is by writing a post on Meta, just as you did :) . (check the "bug" tag tooltip)
